# Building but not publishing

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

recently I have been working on an SSIS solution, however, I have been continuously running into a publishing 'error'. My solution would build without a problem but would not publish and actually run. I have been simply going to previous commits to fix this problem but it always seems to return once I reload the solution another day. There is no build error and I don't touch anything regarding the running of the solution. Is there any long term solutions to this issue? or what the actual cause of something like this to occur?

Comment: Check the executable in both the bin release and debug folders and check the dates to make sure both are current.

Comment: It seems that my debug folder in bin, how could I configure a new one?

Comment: In menu : Project : Properties : Build

Comment: I put the OutputPath as bin but it creates a .ispac file? It should be a .exe right?

Comment: The tag on this question is c# visual-studio.  So you are building from Visual Studio.  Then why are you getting ispac?

Comment: SSIS builds to an ispac file, which is the Integration Services Project Deployment file.  So that is expected.  What version of SQL Server, Visual Studio, and SSDT are you using?  Are you using project or package deployment?  What is the publishing 'error' you receive (a screenshot would be helpful)?  When you mention "publishing", are you referring to the deploy action when you right click an SSIS project in Visual Studio?

Comment: I am using SQL server 2017 in Visual Studio 2019, with the SSDT for vs 2019. I guess 'error' isn't the best word for me to use since no message appears, the project just builds but then never deploys. I have never used visual studios before this so I have no idea why it is not running. In the configuration manager, there is no Platform it is running on, and when I hit new it simply refreshes to default.